# WOW64_CONTEXT ContextFlags data member values?

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

After looking through MSDN documentation of both `Wow64GetThreadContext` and `WOW64_CONTEXT` I have no idea what the possible values are for the `ContextFlags` data member of `WOW64_CONTEXT`. And `ContextFlags` is supposed to be set by the caller and it affects the context.

> lpContext [in, out] A WOW64_CONTEXT structure. The caller must initialize the ContextFlags member of this structure.
>
> The function retrieves a selective context based on the value of the ContextFlags member of the context structure.

I found various macros starting with CONTEXT but none of them seem to have an effect. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: look in *winnt.h* - you can use flags - *WOW64_CONTEXT_CONTROL*,  *WOW64_CONTEXT_INTEGER*, *WOW64_CONTEXT_SEGMENTS* and so on

Comment: @RbMm Much appreciated. May I ask if you found any documentation on them as well? If not would you happen to know the meaning of each one and how they affect the context?

Comment: but look in *winnt.h* here in comments shown which registers returned by flag - *WOW64_CONTEXT_INTEGER* - *AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI*, *WOW64_CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS* - *DB 0-3,6,7*, *WOW64_CONTEXT_CONTROL* - *SS:SP, CS:IP, FLAGS, BP* and so on. for my look this is absolute enough